# How can I persist Facebook access tokens when using Flask and rauth?

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, flask, rauth

When I perform a `get_authorize_url` request to facebook, I am redirected to the following `URL` (seen in the browser):

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/#access_token=sdfsdfasfaf&expires_in=5849
```

But I am unable to obtain this access_token in `flask`: it is not in `request.args`, it is not in `request.query_string`, it is not even there in `request.url`. Maybe flask is having trouble with the `#` character? How can I access that query parameter?

This is the relevant part of my code (derived from the `rauth` [facebook-cli example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/c6447ddb5427246d58e6c2077bdc71404b4d1def/examples/facebook-cli.py)):

```
# rauth OAuth 2.0 service wrapper
graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
facebook = OAuth2Service(name='facebook',
                         authorize_url='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
                         access_token_url=graph_url + 'oauth/access_token',
                         client_id=app.config['FB_CLIENT_ID'],
                         client_secret=app.config['FB_CLIENT_SECRET'],
                         base_url=graph_url)

...

@app.route('/facebook/login')
def login():
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorized', _external=True)
    params = {'scope': 'read_stream',
              'response_type': 'token',
              'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}
    return redirect(facebook.get_authorize_url(**params))

@app.route('/facebook/authorized')
def authorized():
    # I am not able to find the access_token
    print dir(request)
    print request.args
    print request.query_string
    print request.url

    ...
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `response_type` `code` instead of `token` as the former flow tends to work better for web applications where the latter flow was used in the command line example script. (Please note, the cli example is not intended to be used as a model for web apps!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of URI marked by '#' is called fragment identifier. It is not transmitted to the server and can be processed on client side only, by JS, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [Facebook Flask example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples/facebook) and use the code response, there's no need for any JavaScript. In fact in general that is not a requirement for OAuth consumers.

Comment: Right. But the facebook example is performing authorization requests all the time. I want to somehow "save" the access_token for future use, so that the user does not need to authorize my application each time that I want to send a request to the facebook API.

Comment: You can do this by accessing the token on the session instance like so: `session.access_token`. Then persist this data somewhere safe.